# How do I reduce the width of the cell which is longer

Tags: css, xhtml, html-table

I am generating the Html in Excel sheet and entire table is fine and except the 
two cells are much wider. How do I reduce the width of those cells. I tried changing 
the width and everything but no use. It works fine on Html table. On Excel spreadsheet it looks different.

Comment: Can you add some sourcecode for us to see? It's very difficult to tell you what is wrong if we can't see it for ourselves :)

Comment: Are you generating an HTML table or an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @MikeWyatt :It works fine on Html table .On excel spread sheet it looks different

Comment: What library are you using to generate the spreadsheet?  Source code would be nice, as Kyle already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Chrome v6.0.472.62 and Firefox 3.6.10, both on Ubuntu 10.04, allow:

```
th, td {width: 7em; max-width: 8em; }
```

the `max-width` seems to be the important part, preventing the cell from growing. Also the `white-space: nowrap` is important if you don't want the cell to wrap the contents within the defined `width`.

There's a demo over at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/agemu4), I've not hidden the overflow on the overflowing cell, deliberately so that you could see it in effect, though in real use you'll need to work out some way of showing the actual contents of the cell without it obscuring the content of its neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a HTML table, just two cells cant be big. its either one entire row bigger or one entire column bigger.

If that is the case, the dimensions are best-fit based on the content of those cells. Therefore, the width attribute won't take effect. if wordwrap is not helping, changing the fontsize of that exact cell alone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to check: make sure that you're outputting the proper number of cells per row taking careful account of row/col spanning. If you miss one somewhere, the whole thing will be screwy.